# Простая авторизация на сайте

Tags: .htaccess, авторизация

Делаю сервер для личного пользования: база данных с веб интерфейсом. Какой способ авторизации проще? Можно ли обойтись htaccess? Красивая страница логина не нужна. Ну и хотелось бы чтобы ее не взломал первый попавшися школьник.

Answer (score 0):

Для одного пользователя и сервера Apache **базовая авторизация** единственно верный вариант.
Чтобы закрыть директорию, в неё нужно поместить два файла – .htaccess и .htpasswd.

**Файл .htaccess:**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authorize" //сообщение в окне ввода логина и пароля
AuthUserFile /folder/.htpasswd // СЕРВЕРНЫЙ путь до файла с паролями.
Require valid-user
```

Далее кодируй логин и пароль, лучше bcrypt, где? Гугли!
Например, логин: superadmin, пароль: superpass

**Файл .htpasswd:**

```
superadmin:$2a$12$PGH1mnHBViYTEjGUQNr3.ubTpJx3Tb0R2nRBUdxnMi4W5ov.xWW.6
```

Защиты от подбора нет, но процедура авторизации довольна специфична и практически не доступна автоматизированной атаке)))
Для полного успокоения записывай в отдельную табличку айпи и заголовки браузера для всех авторизации в БД, периодически мониторя.